# java.util.Date return falsy date after parssing a string date

Tags: java, java.util.date

I'm trying to format a string that stores a date in format `yyyy-MM-dd` as `dd-MM-yyyy`. Here is my code :

```
String dateString = "1991-08-03";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);

System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

I don't know from where comes the problem, but i get this as a result :

[image]

EDIT : wrong Date Format in line 2 (dd-MM-yyyy), the format should match the string (yyyy-MM-dd).
A Big thanks to @Luiggi Mendoza for his response : You should store it as Date. The Date object knows nothing about format, that's why you use a separate class to provide a proper format to display the Date.

Comment: The string stored in `dateString` does not match the format stated in `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: **1991-08-03** vs **dd-MM-yyyy**. Voting to close as typo. (You can set your `DateFormat` to be non lenient.)

Comment: that's exactly what i want to do.. get the date from a input type date (wich comes in this format yyyy-MM-dd), format it to this format dd-MM-yyyy and ten store it as a date object.

Comment: @BOB: If you're going to keep it as a `Date`, why reformat it at all? Do you not understand that you're *parsing* it with a pattern that doesn't match the string you've got?

Comment: yeah you're right. what if i want to store it with this format dd/MM/yyyy ?!

Comment: You should store it as `Date`. The `Date` object knows **nothing** about format, that's why you use a separate class to provide a proper format to display the `Date`.

Comment: So you need to parse it with one SimpleDateFormat, and then format it with another... assuming you *really* need to store it as a string at all.

Answer (score -2):

```
String dateString = "1991-08-03";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
long time = date.getTime();
Date newDate = new Date(time);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(newDate));
```

Comment: Your first format string is broken - it should be `yyyy-MM-dd`, not `YYYY-mm-dd`. Case matters.